Why is my Auto DevOps job unable to access my storage?
I have set up AutoDevops in Gitlab with a docker executor and cannot access my Gitlab url. The log is as follows:

Using Docker executor with image docker:20.10.12 ...
Starting service docker:20.10.12-dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:20.10.12-dind ...
Using docker image sha256:1a42336ff683d7dadd320ea6fe9d93a5b101474346302d23f96c9b4546cb414d for docker:20.10.12-dind with digest docker@sha256:6f2ae4a5fd85ccf85cdd829057a34ace894d25d544e5e4d9f2e7109297fedf8d ...
Waiting for services to be up and running (timeout 30 seconds)...
*** WARNING: Service runner-tytmdys1f-project-4-concurrent-0-6229c66d91c8b780-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
start service container: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-tytmdys1f-project-4-concurrent-0-6229c66d91c8b780-docker-0 AS /runner-tytmdys1f-project-4-concurrent-0-6229c66d91c8b780-docker-0-wait-for-service/service (services.go:215:0s)
Service container logs:
2024-05-19T19:34:59.690649519Z ip: can't find device 'ip_tables'
2024-05-19T19:34:59.691689777Z ip_tables              36864  0
2024-05-19T19:34:59.691857739Z x_tables               53248 10 xt_nat,xt_MASQUERADE,xt_addrtype,ipt_REJECT,xt_state,xt_conntrack,xt_LOG,xt_tcpudp,nft_compat,ip_tables
2024-05-19T19:34:59.692296252Z modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
2024-05-19T19:34:59.694305092Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2024-05-19T19:34:59.694322297Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2024-05-19T19:34:59.694376758Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
2024-05-19T19:34:59.695375308Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)


Pulling docker image docker:20.10.12 ...
Using docker image sha256:15a9bc7c6340df2ac9d6c8196ca1d905180ddf2ca8b29a8d98f5422e2e5ccf85 for docker:20.10.12 with digest docker@sha256:a729cce205a05b0b86dc8dca87823efaffc3f74979fe7dc86a707c2fbf631b61 ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-tytmdys1f-project-4-concurrent-0 via gitirkutskoilru...
Getting source from Git repository
00:06
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/..../.git/
fatal: unable to access 'https://.....git/': Could not resolve host: ....
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:02
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: gl-code-quality-report.json: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/...)
ERROR: No files to upload
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

The runner is on the same machine with the Gitlab installation. How to correct this? It looks like the runner from the docker image cannot resolve the url.

I added the ip address of the host machine to the daemon.json dns list, and this problem has gone. The new problem is:
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=registry.gitlab.com%2Fgitlab-org%2Fci-cd%2Fcodequality&tag=0.96.0": dial tcp: lookup docker on 10.3.40.17:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:43918->10.3.40.17:53: read: no route to host
